# EF Core configuration problem with owned type used in 2 different classes

Tags: c#, mysql, ef-core-2.2

I'm using entity framework core and I would like to use the same owned type in 2 different classes. This is normally fine however in my case I am getting an error.

I am using a MySql database and the requirement is that all booleans are mapped to a field in the database with column type tinyint(1).  To achieve this in my OnModelCreating method I loop through all the properties and if the property is boolean I map it to tinyint(1).  However as soon as I use the same owned type in 2 different classes I get the error.

Below I have written a demo program which shows my problem.  All you need to recreate this is 2 tables, organisations and contacts.  Both with fields id, street and home. To use MySQL I have installed the nuget package MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore (v8.0.17).  I've run the code in a .net core 2.2  console app.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion;

namespace MyDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           using(var ctx = new MyDbContext())
            {
                var contact = new Contact
                {                
                    Address = new Address
                    {
                        Street = "x",
                        Home = true
                    }
                };
                ctx.Contacts.Add(contact);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }


    public class MyDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext()        
        {

        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("{my connection string}");                
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
                .OwnsOne(p => p.Address,
                a =>
                {
                    a.Property(p => p.Street)
                    .HasColumnName("street")
                    .HasDefaultValue("");
                    a.Property(p => p.Home)
                    .HasColumnName("home")
                    .HasDefaultValue(false);
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Organisation>()
                .OwnsOne(p => p.Address,
                a =>
                {
                    a.Property(p => p.Street)
                    .HasColumnName("street")
                    .HasDefaultValue("");
                    a.Property(p => p.Home)
                    .HasColumnName("home")
                    .HasDefaultValue(false);
                });

            var entityTypes = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()          
            .ToList();

            foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
            {
                var properties = entityType
                    .GetProperties()
                    .ToList();


                foreach (var property in properties)
                {
                    if (property.PropertyInfo == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (property.PropertyInfo.PropertyType.IsBoolean())
                    {
                        modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType)
                        .Property(property.Name)
                        .HasConversion(new BoolToZeroOneConverter<short>())
                        .HasColumnType("tinyint(1)");
                    }
                }
            }

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<Contact>Contacts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Organisation>Organisations { get; set; }
    }

    public class Contact
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }

        //other contact fields
    }

    public class Organisation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }

        //other organisation fields
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public bool Home{ get; set; }
    }

    public static class TypeExtensions
    {
        public static bool IsBoolean(this Type type)
        {
            Type t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) ?? type;
            return t == typeof(bool);
        }
    }
}
```

After running the above code the error message that shows up is System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'Address' cannot be added to the model because a weak entity type with the same name already exists'.  The part of the code that throws the error is this bit

```
if (property.PropertyInfo.PropertyType.IsBoolean())
{
     modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType)
    .Property(property.Name)
    .HasConversion(new BoolToZeroOneConverter<short>())
    .HasColumnType("tinyint(1)");
}
```

How can I change my code so that the OnModelCreating method runs without error so that the contact record is saved correctly to the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update (EF Core 3.x):**

Still no public way to get `EntityTypeBuilder`, but at least the constructor argument has been modified to be `IMutableEntityType` type, so only

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
```

is needed, and the corresponding code now is

```
var entityTypeBuilder = new EntityTypeBuilder(entityType);
```

**Original (EF Core 2.x):**

The problem is that the `ClrType` is not enough to identify the owned entity type, hence `modelBuilder.Entity(Type)` cannot be used to obtain the `EntityTypeBuilder` instance needed for fluently configuring the entity properties.

Seems like there is no good *public* way to do that in EF Core 2.x, so all I can suggest is to use some of the EF Core *internals* (luckily publicly accessible under the typical internal usage warning).

You'd need the following `using`s:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
```

The first is for `EntityTypeBuilder` class, the second is for `AsEntityType()` extension method which gives you access to the internal class implementing the `IEntityType`, and in particular the `Builder` property.

The modified code looks like this:

```
var entityTypes = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .ToList();

foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
{
    var properties = entityType
        .GetProperties()
        .ToList();

    // (1)
    var entityTypeBuilder = new EntityTypeBuilder(entityType.AsEntityType().Builder);

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if (property.PropertyInfo == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (property.PropertyInfo.PropertyType.IsBoolean())
        {
            entityTypeBuilder // (2)
            .Property(property.Name)
            .HasConversion(new BoolToZeroOneConverter<short>())
            .HasColumnType("tinyint(1)");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just updated my code and it all works with no errors.  Thanks!

Comment: @DaveBarnett Public - still no. See the update. In fact everything is public, but the constructor is marked as `[EntityFrameworkInternal]`