# IMutableEntityType.GetProperties() doesn't include a property that I want

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a bunch of models that all make use of a class that I have created. They have properties of type `Measurement`. This `Measurement` class is not in itself an entity or a model that I want mapped to a database table. It's simply a type for passing around values and units in a pair, along with a bunch of methods and operators for managing operations on those values and units.

I have created a `ValueConverter` so that I can represent the properties of this type in my models as strings in the database.

```cs
ValueConverter<Measurement, string> measurementConverter = new ValueConverter<Measurement, string>
(
    v => v.ToString(),
    v => new Measurement(v)
);
```

Then, my plan is, in the `OnModelCreating()` method in my `DbContext`, to loop over all my entities and their properties, and use `property.SetValueConverter(measurementConverter);` on them if they are of the `Measurement` type. This way, all the Measurements in my models will automatically be able to save to and load from the database, and I don't have to keep extra string representation fields in my models.

Here's the loop I'm talking about:

```cs
foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    foreach (var property in entity.GetProperties())
    {
        if(property.ClrType == typeof(Measurement)) { property.SetValueConverter(measurementConverter); }
    }
}
```

The problem lies with the `GetProperties()` method. The documentation summary for it says this:

> This API only returns scalar properties and does not return navigation properties

The result of that is that none of my `Measurement` properties are returned by it at all. I believe that Entity Framework thinks that the `Measurement` class is actually its own model, so it doesn't treat it like a normal property. Of course, this means that the `ValueConverter` is never set on it and the whole solution doesn't work the way I want it to.

My first thought was to turn the `Measurement` class into a struct instead, as it is already immutable and there's no real reason why it couldn't have been a struct in the first place. Wouldn't that make it clear to Entity Framework that this is a scalar property and should be included in the `GetProperties()` return? I thought so, but apparently not. I still get the same behavior after changing it.

I would like to avoid putting an attribute on every `Measurement` property in every model, so if there's any way to just tell Entity Framework that all of these properties are in fact bindable, that would be awesome. If not, then how do I mark them out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's annoying that EF Core currently does not provide a good way to map user defined types. There is a plugin mechanism which is used by NET Topology suite, bit it requires too much plumbing code.

So, the `GetProperties` issue:

> This API only returns scalar properties and does not return navigation properties

Well, once you know that EF Core treats your type as entity, hence treats properties of that type as navigation properties, you can use `GetNavigations` instead of `GetProperties`:

```
foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    foreach (var navigation in entityType.GetNavigations().ToList())
    {
        if (navigation.ClrType == typeof(Measurement))
        {
            var entityTypeBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType);
            entityTypeBuilder
                .Property<Measurement>(navigation.Name)
                .HasConversion(measurementConverter);
        }
    }
}
```

The only problem is this

```
var entityTypeBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType);
```

As we can see here [EF Core configuration problem with owned type used in 2 different classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57692369/ef-core-configuration-problem-with-owned-type-used-in-2-different-classes/57695222#57695222), this is problematic (does not work) for owned entity types. And making it work requires using the internal API:

```
var entityTypeBuilder = new EntityTypeBuilder(entityType.AsEntityType().Builder);
```

In your own answer you say that using the internal API is "bad". IMHO the only bad thing is that the library does not provide a "good" public API for that. From the other side, fortunately all "internal" EF Core APIs are publicly available and can be used for scenarios like this when the public API is not sufficient. The only difference is that you have to watch the API changes when upgrading the newer version and update accordingly. Considering how many times they break the public APIs, this should not be a big deal/concern.

Comment: Hah! So the thought is that they break the public API so often that there's not really any additive risk from using the internal API? I actually thought about opening an issue on the github repo with this code.

Comment: Well, you can open an issue of course. My point is that it's not so big deal/showstopper like the lack of public *and* internal way to do what you need. Something is better than nothing :) It's a big step compared to the over encapsulated  EF6 where one need to use reflection to access private/internal fields etc.

Comment: Gotcha! This is my first foray into Entity Framework at all, so I had no idea. I'm accepting this answer because I just tried it, and it works just as well as mine, while being significantly less convoluted.

Answer (score 2):

Now, I'm not saying this is a good idea, but I ended up finding a way to do this.

```cs
var entities = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().ToList();

for(int i = 0; i < entities.Count; i++)
{
    var entity = entities[i];
    foreach(var property in entity.ClrType.GetProperties().Where(p => 
        p.PropertyType == typeof(Measurement) && !Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(NotMappedAttribute))
    ))
    {
        // This API supports the Entity Framework Core infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.
        // This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.internal.internalentitytypebuilder

        var entityTypeBuilderType = typeof(EntityTypeBuilder<>).MakeGenericType(entity.ClrType);
        Model model = modelBuilder.Model as Model;
        var internalModelBuilder = new InternalModelBuilder(model);
        var internalEntityTypeBuilder = new InternalEntityTypeBuilder(entity.AsEntityType(), internalModelBuilder);
        var entityTypeBuilder = (EntityTypeBuilder)Activator.CreateInstance(entityTypeBuilderType, internalEntityTypeBuilder);
        entityTypeBuilder.Property<Measurement>(property.Name).HasConversion(measurementConverter);
    }
}
```

The reason this is bad is because it used a bunch of Internal classes. As you can see in the comment:

> This API supports the Entity Framework Core infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.
>   This API may change or be removed in future releases.

The reason it has to be this way is because the `EntityTypeBuilder` *must use a generic of the entity type that you are trying to configure.* Otherwise, later configuration will not work and will report your entities as in a "shadow state".

In order to use the generic, you have to use `MakeGenericType` and then `Activator.CreateInstance`, and then the `EntityTypeBuilder` needs an `InternalEntityTypeBuilder` as a parameter for its constructor, and so on... the chain of dependencies runs down to the `Model`, which you can get from the modelBuilder.

Long story short... this works perfectly, but *use at your own risk.*

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to submit my own answer here because I ran into this problem and found a way (using some of OP's answer) to accomplish this without getting into the internals. My use case was that I needed to be able to store primitive collections like `long[]` and `string[]` because it's a feature of Postgres that I'm using, but the InMemory provider doesn't support it. I didn't want to have huge blocks of code manually setting value converters and comparers for every single prop like this.

You start by grabbing all the relevant classes using reflection. Then you grab the relevant props by querying for an attribute (`LongCollection` and `StringCollection` in my case). Finally, you can add a `PropertyInfo` to a `IMutableEntityTypeBuilder` using `AddProperty(PropertyInfo prop)`. So here's my code.

```cs
protected void ConvertPrimitiveInMemoryCollections(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    // Get all the relevant classes and map what you'll need from them
    var entities = this.GetType().Assembly
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(x => x.IsConcrete())
        // In my case, I know if it implements this interface it's relevant here
        .Where(x => typeof(IDomainEvent).IsAssignableFrom(x))
        .Select(type => new
        {
            // This is sort of like get or add the entity to the model
            entityTypeBuilder = builder.Model.FindEntityType(type) ?? builder.Model.AddEntityType(type),
            stringProps = type.GetProperties()
                .Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(StringCollectionAttribute)))
                .ToArray(),
            longProps = type.GetProperties()
                .Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(LongCollectionAttribute)))
                .ToArray()
        })
        .Where(x => x.stringProps.Any() || x.longProps.Any())
        .ToArray();

    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        foreach (var prop in entity.stringProps)
        {
            var property = entity.entityTypeBuilder.AddProperty(prop);

            property.SetValueConverter(StringConverter);
            property.SetValueComparer(StringComparer);
        }

        foreach (var prop in entity.longProps)
        {
            var property = entity.entityTypeBuilder.AddProperty(prop);

            property.SetValueConverter(LongConverter);
            property.SetValueComparer(LongComparer);
        }
    }
}
```