# Is there a way to map complex type to the string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is there a way to map complex type to the string?

I'm doing custom mapping like following:

```
foreach (var pb in modelBuilder.Model
            .GetEntityTypes()
            .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
            .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(SomeComplexType) && !Attribute.IsDefined(p.GetMemberInfo(false, false), typeof(Padding)))
            .Select(p => modelBuilder.Entity(p.DeclaringEntityType.ClrType).Property(p.Name)))
        {
            pb.HasConversion(new ValueConverter<SomeComplexType, string>(
                v => v.ToString(),
                v => SomeComplexType.Parse(v)));
        }
```

But when running migrations I get

> The property 'SomeEntity.ComplexTypeProperty' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'SomeComplexType' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

So I want to be able to map complex type to string and save it as such.

Comment: The problem is `.Property(p.Name)` call - these by convention are not properties, but navigations. So instead of `GetProperties()` use `GetNavigations()` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57697901/imutableentitytype-getproperties-doesnt-include-a-property-that-i-want/57709893#57709893

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to JSON encode it:

```
pb.HasConversion(new ValueConverter<SomeComplexType, string>(
    v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
    v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeComplexType>(v)));
```

In ASP.NET Core 3.0, you'd use `System.Text.Json` instead, so the methods would be `JsonSerializer.ToString(v)` and `JsonSerializer.Parse<SomeComplexType>(v)`